# HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException with Hibernate, Mariadb and Spring transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, mariadb

We are migrating application from oracle to Mariadb. Using container transactions and Spring transaction management. I am getting error for code where the one record is saved and updated in same transaction(Service bean method). Same code is working fine for Oracle database.

I am the only one who is connected to the mariadb database. Help will be appreciated.

Error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException:
    Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0];
    actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException:
    Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0];
    actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

JDK: 1.6, Tomcat: 7.0.65, Spring: 4.1, hibernate: 4.2.21

mariadb version: 10.1.13-MariaDB

driver: mariadb-java-client-1.1.9

Dialects: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

and 
i tried with org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect also same error is coming.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEAL")
public class Deal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1196605299069938794L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SK_DEAL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "Deal_SEQ")
    @TableGenerator(name = "Deal_SEQ", pkColumnValue = "DEAL_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "INT_DEAL_ID", length = 50)
    private String internalDealId;

    @Column(name = "DEAL_DESC", length = 100)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_UPDATED_ID")
    private SysUser lastUpdatedId;

    @Version
    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED")
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE_USER_TZ")
    private Date creationDateUserTz;

    @Type(type = "date")
    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    private Date endDate;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getInternalDealId() {
        return this.internalDealId;
    }

    public void setInternalDealId(String internalDealId) {
        this.internalDealId = internalDealId;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public SysUser getLastUpdatedId() {
        return this.lastUpdatedId;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedId(SysUser lastUpdatedId) {
        this.lastUpdatedId = lastUpdatedId;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getCreationDateUserTz() {
        return creationDateUserTz;
    }

    public void setCreationDateUserTz(Date creationDateUserTz) {
        this.creationDateUserTz = creationDateUserTz;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("{")
        .append("id=").append(id)
        .append(",internalDealId=").append(internalDealId)
        .append(",description=").append(description)
        .append(",lastUpdatedId=").append(lastUpdatedId != null ? lastUpdatedId.getId() : null)
        .append(",lastUpdated=").append(lastUpdated)
        .append(",creationDate=").append(creationDate)
        .append(",creationDateUserTz=").append(creationDateUserTz)
        .append(",endDate=").append(endDate)
        .append("}")
        .toString();
    }

}
```

Service class method

```
@Override
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public DealVO addNew(DealVO vo) {
        Deal deal = new Deal();
        vo.setEndDate(new Date());
        deal = convertDealVOToDeal(vo, deal);
        dealDao.save(deal);
        //Some other logic based on creation date
        //setting some other deal properties
        dealDao.save(deal);
        //original logger is removed as it contains sensitive deal info
        vo.setCreationDate(deal.getCreationDate());
        vo.setCreationDateUserTz(deal.getCreationDateUserTz());
        vo.setId(deal.getId());
        return vo;
    }
```

Dao class methods:

```
public Session getSession() {
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save(T domain) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(domain);
    }
```

Queries generated after control coming out of service method

```
insert into DEAL (INT_DEAL_ID, DEAL_DESC, LAST_UPDATED_ID, CREATION_DATE,    
                  CREATION_DATE_USER_TZ, END_DATE, SK_DEAL_ID)
     values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

update DEAL set INT_DEAL_ID=?, DEAL_DESC=?, LAST_UPDATED_ID=?,
                CREATION_DATE=?, CREATION_DATE_USER_TZ=?, END_DATE=?
     where SK_DEAL_ID=? and LAST_UPDATED=?
```

Comment: This appends every time, in a single unit test, or some times in production/stressed environment ?

Comment: every time unit testing, code is not yet moved to UAT

Comment: And if you try a pure sql script within a transaction you get what using a sql client ?

Comment: check your mariadb transaction level configuration https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/set-transaction/

Comment: The queries i provided are from appliction logs we enabled show_sql, format_sql and use_sql_comments. 
Same queries are working fine in sql client but not for the same record because current record is not saved.


I am not good on database side, Please suggest what are the parameters we have to set on MariaDb to make it work with the Hibernate container transactions

Comment: I think you can try to set READ COMMITTED as Isolation Levels because Oracle work like this by default.

Comment: So do you have args of the query in your logs ? In hibernate be sure to configure as PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. And you can test to delete @Transactional from save method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
We modified both GLOBAL and TRANSACTION level to READ COMMITTED in mariadb still same issue

Comment: OK try to use a number (int or long) as @Version of your entity maybe there is a issue with timestamp

Comment: Thorynque Thank you for you help. Issue is resolved.

@version is the issue. In side application date is with milliseconds.

In Oracle we used database column type timestamp. Which is saving milli seconds also.


in Maria DB our team used type datetime by default date time is not saving milli seconds. We change it to datetime(6).

Comment: I think it's interesting to put your comment as answer and check that it solves your question.